# Curl for Windows - curl couldn't open file C:\test.txt

Tags: windows, curl, path

I am trying to use CURL on a Windows device and cannot work out the correct syntax for uploading a file in a specific location, was hoping someone may have an idea.

At the moment the syntax I am trying is below;

```
curl --proxy-ntlm --proxy-user domain\username:password --proxy proxy.server:80 -vk 'filename=hello.txt' -F 'file=@C:\hello.txt' https://upload.site
```

But all I am getting back is `curl: (26) couldn't open file "C:\hello.txt"`

I have tried @C:\\hello.txt, @C:/hello.txt, @"C:\hello.txt" but still getting the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas where I maybe going wrong? I can't believe it should be as hard as I am making this out to be :-)

Comment: Is the file _C:\hello.txt_ present and readable?

Answer (score 5):

On Window 7, i got same issue.
i just fix ' to "

For example:

```
curl --proxy-ntlm --proxy-user domain\username:password --proxy proxy.server:80 -vk "filename=hello.txt" -F "file=@C:\hello.txt" https://upload.site
```

Comment: Works well for me on Windows 10. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue - make sure your txt file is a text file. I had output.rtp and got this error. I renamed it to output.txt and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error is fixed in version 7_54_0

https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/bdf162af255b8dc1498da6f312f04fe2e83f1a48

A compiled version for Windows is available at http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.54.0

I tested it with the following Windows versions

1. Window Server 2003
2. Windows 7
3. Windows Server 2012

My curl command looks like this
`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@test.csv" http://localhost:8099/document`